# Performance of position absolute layouts vs Flexbox 2

Tags: html, css, performance, browser, flexbox

I am working on a large scale javascript app that heavily uses the newest flexbox spec (`display: flex`) right now and we're seeing some layout performance problems.

I'm just wondering if someone has insight as to performance comparisons of the new flexbox model (`display: flex`) and using `position: absolute` with `top,right,bottom,left` options set.

[Here](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/10/Flexbox-layout-isn-t-slow) is a relevant article, but no comparisons between these two, despite commenters asking for it.

Comment: What are you refering to by `flexbox 2`?

Comment: As many rewrites as the spec has been through Flexbox has always been level 1. There isn't a Flexbox level 2 spec yet. I suspect the OP is simply referring to the latest revision.

Comment: Sorry I was referring to the newest version of flexbox i.e. ```display: flex``` rather than ```display: box``` or ```display: flexbox```